# Is it possible to substitute into `i` element in data.table[i, j , by]

Tags: r, data.table, non-standard-evaluation

I'm wondering if it's possible to substitute expressions into the `i` portion of data.table. I've set up a deeply nested list that contains preset parameters to perform subsetting depending on which sub-group a user has selected in a shiny app. I'm suspecting that it is not possible but am hoping to get confirmation one way or the other.

If it's not possible, I welcome any ideas for alternative solutions.

Basic example

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(
  y = rep(c('a','b'),5),
  x = 1:10
)

exp1 = "x > 5"

dt[y == "a" & substitute(exp1)]
# Error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Comment: Don't use eval parse. Use new env argument in data.table, which was created exactly to solve problems like yours. You can read more about it in new vignette https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html

Comment: @jangorecki the new env argument is currently only available in the dev version. The CRAN version of 1.14.8 hasn't had this feature yet.

Comment: Yes I know, just run data.table::update_dev_pkg()

Comment: @jangorecki - I'm aware of the new env arg and wish that was a viable option. However, the shiny app I'm working on is part a larger group of apps all managed by the same `renv` set up. So I'm quite cautious towards using a dev version of any package in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach is like this:

```
library(data.table)
exp1 = "x > 5" |> str2lang()
(ll <- substitute(
    dt[y == "a" & e1],
    list(
        e1 = exp1
    )
))
eval(ll)
```

I think this is a good approach because it maintains idiomatic `data.table`'s look. For example, if you want `dt[y == "a" & x > 5, .(mm = length(x)), by = "y"]`:

```
(ll <- substitute(
    dt[y == "a" & e1, .(mm = f1(e2)), by = e3], # Change right here and maintain data.table's look
    list(
        e1 = exp1,
        # e1 = "x > 5" |> str2lang(),
        e2 = quote(x), # Allow more flexibilities
        e3 = "y", # Allow more flexibilities
        f1 = quote(length) # Allow more flexibilities
    )
))
eval(ll)
```

It is also similar to the `substitute2` and `env` approaches proposed in developmental version of `data.table`.

Comment: Yes, env arg just wraps i, j, by into substitute calls

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this! In your second example, could you explain the need to add `quote` for `e2` and `f1`. Or refer me to some documentation around that?

Comment: @Jamie Sorry for the late reply. Without `quote` in `e2`, it will become `e2 = x`. This will become the case of `e1` (i.e., find this variable `x` somewhere and substitute the **value** of variable `x` to `e2`). Try `x <- 3; (ll <- substitute(dt[y == "a" & e1, .(mm = f1(e2)), by = e3], list(e1 = "x > 5" |> str2lang(), e2 = x, e3 = "y", f1 = quote(length))))`, the result is `dt[y == "a" & x > 5, .(mm = length(3)), by = "y"]`

Comment: Alternatively, You can use `e2 = as.name("x")` instead of `e2 = quote(x)`. In this case, it helps in ease of interpretation is that we want the name/symbol `x` and **not the value of** `x`.

Comment: The canonical resources for this stuff are [R Manuals-The R language definition-Computing on the language](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Computing-on-the-language) and `help(quote)`, `help(expression)`, `help(parse)`...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `eval(parse(..))` but there are [some concerns related to  it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)

```
library(data.table)

exp1 = "x > 5"
dt[y == "a" & eval(parse(text = exp1))]

#   y x
#1: a 7
#2: a 9
```

Comment: does `eval(str2lang(expr1))` also have concerns? or even `eval(str2expression(expr1))`

Comment: Hmm...I haven't used them so I am not sure.

Comment: @Onyambu the `eval(parse(..))`, `eval(str2lang(expr1))` and `eval(str2expression(expr1))` all require that the expressions are built by **string manipulation** (concatenate, replace...), then parsed. The authors of `data.table` has quite a [good summary](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html#use-of-parse-eval) about its problems.