# Evaluating `i` in data.table's `set()`

Tags: r, data.table

Imagine I am creating a new column in a `data.table` object:

```
require(data.table)
data(iris)
dt.iris <- data.table(iris)

dt.iris[,shortSpecies:=substr(Species,1,5)]
```

Now, instead of doing this directly with `:=`, I want to have a function that takes that code for creating a column as an argument and then evaluates it. I ended up with this:

```
make_new_col <- function(inputDT, newColName, construction){
  set(
    x = inputDT, 
    j = newColName, 
    value=eval(expr = parse(text = construction), envir=inputDT)
    )
}

dt.iris <- make_new_col(
  inputDT = dt.iris, 
  newColName = 'shortSpecies', 
  construction = 'substr(Species,1,5)'
)
```

This works, but now I want to add a condition, i.e. to make an equivalent of `dt.iris[Sepal.Length>5,shortSpecies:=substr(Species,1,5)]`. I need somehow to pass the condition to the `i=` part of `set()` to be evaluated, and I can't find a working solution.

Comment: avoid eval parse, it is considered bad practice in R because it expose function for "computing on the language"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide a standard condition `if` `cond` is `missing`.

```
> library(data.table)
> make_new_col3 <- function(inputDT, cond, newColName, construction) {
+   stopifnot(ncol(inputDT) > 0)
+   if (missing(cond)) cond <- "`mode<-`(inputDT[[1]], 'logical')"
+   set(
+     x=inputDT, 
+     i=(w <- which(eval(parse(text=cond), envir=inputDT))),
+     j=newColName, 
+     value=eval(parse(text=construction), envir=inputDT[w, ])
+   )
+ }
```

```
> dt.iris <- make_new_col3(
+   inputDT=dt.iris, 
+   cond='Sepal.Length > 5',
+   newColName='shortSpecies', 
+   construction='substr(Species, 1, 5)'
+ )
> head(dt.iris)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species shortSpecies
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa        setos
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa         <NA>
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa         <NA>
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa         <NA>
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa         <NA>
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa        setos
```

```
> dt.iris <- make_new_col3(
+   inputDT=dt.iris, 
+   # cond='Sepal.Length > 5',
+   newColName='shortSpecies', 
+   construction='substr(Species, 1, 5)'
+ )
> head(dt.iris)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species shortSpecies
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa        setos
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa        setos
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa        setos
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa        setos
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa        setos
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa        setos
```

---

*Data:*

```
dt.iris <- as.data.table(iris)
```

Comment: looks interesting, thank you! Could you explain a bit what happens in that `mode<-` part and why it is better then just `i=NULL` in `set()`? Thanks!

Comment: @VasilyA In need to offer the `text=` argument an appropriate substitute, `mode<-` converts first column `dt.iris[[1]]` to logical and results in a vector of `c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, ...)` (or `c(TRUE, NA, TRUE, ...)` if there are `NA`'s). So every row with a `TRUE` there will receive a short name. Should do the same, is more concise and probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

So far I came to this solution:

```
make_new_col_cond <- function(inputDT, newColName, condition=NULL, construction){
  
  ret_i <- NULL
  ret_val <- eval(expr = parse(text = construction), envir=inputDT)
  
  if (!is.null(condition)) {
    ret_i <- which(eval(expr = parse(text=condition), envir=inputDT))
    ret_val <- ret_val[ret_i]
  }
  
  set(
    i = ret_i,
    x = inputDT, 
    j = newColName, 
    value = ret_val
    )
}

# usage:
dt.iris <- make_new_col_cond(
  inputDT = dt.iris, 
  condition = 'Sepal.Length>5',
  newColName = 'shortSpecies', 
  construction = 'substr(Species,1,5)'
)
```

Looks a bit ugly but it does the job. Any suggestions on optimizing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question to yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76134803/9454926). You can read my answer together with @jangorecki
's comments therein. My approach is to use metaprogramming/computing on the language to construct the desired `[` call:

1. Let's start with the basic:

```r
ll <- substitute(
    dt[cond, newColName := construction], # You make a template here with your standard data.table `[` syntax
    list(
        dt = quote(dt.iris), # Replace `dt` in the template with the code `dt.iris`
                             # Use `quote(dt.iris)` to tell R to treat `dt.iris`
                             # as a piece of code instead of the actual dt.iris variable/data.table
        cond = quote(Sepal.Length > 5), # Replace `cond` in the template with the code `Sepal.Length > 5`
        newColName = quote(shortSpecies), # Similar to above
        construction = quote(substr(Species, 1, 5)) # Similar to above
    )
)
cat(deparse(ll), "\n") # dt.iris[Sepal.Length > 5, `:=`(shortSpecies, substr(Species, 1, 5))]
eval(ll) # when you're satisfy with your constructed `[` call, run it with `eval` to get results
```

You can see that you are working at the R code level/expressions (i.e., metaprogramming/computing on the R language) and not string manipulation level (i.e., manipulate strings with string functions to produce one string, then `parse`, then `eval`). These string manipulation or `eval(parse())` approaches are usually ugly, inflexible (difficult to adapt for changing requirements) and unsafe (vulnerable to code injection), so you should avoid them.

2. Let's make a function:

```
make_new_col_expr <- function(inputDT, cond, newColName, construction) {
    ll <- substitute(
        dt[cond, newColName := construction], # Our template
        list(
            dt = substitute(inputDT), # See details below to understand `substitute` usage here
            cond = if (missing(cond)) substitute() else substitute(cond), # `substitute()` is missing, similar to `quote(expr =)`
            newColName = substitute(newColName),
            construction = substitute(construction)
        )
    )
    cat(deparse(ll), "\n")
    eval(ll)
}
make_new_col_expr(dt.iris, Sepal.Length > 5, shortSpecies, substr(Species, 1, 5))
# dt.iris[Sepal.Length > 5, `:=`(shortSpecies, substr(Species, 1, 5))] 

make_new_col_expr(dt.iris,, shortSpecies, substr(Species, 1, 5))
# dt.iris[, `:=`(shortSpecies, substr(Species, 1, 5))]
```

To understand the usage of `substitute(inputDT)`, below are the relevant quotes:

> > Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in env, it is unchanged. **If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function or explicitly created using delayedAssign(), the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol**. If it is an ordinary variable, its value is substituted...
>
> --`?substitute` or [web](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html)

> > Promise objects are part of R’s lazy evaluation mechanism. They contain three slots: a value, an expression, and an environment. **When a function is called the arguments are matched and then each of the formal arguments is bound to a promise. The expression that was given for that formal argument** and a pointer to the environment the function was called from are stored in the promise.
> > Until that argument is accessed there is no value associated with the promise. When the argument is accessed, the stored expression is evaluated in the stored environment, and the result is returned. The result is also saved by the promise. **The substitute function will extract the content of the expression slot**. This allows the programmer to access either the value or the expression associated with the promise.
>
> --[promise objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects) in R Language Definition

First, you run `make_new_col_expr(dt.iris, Sepal.Length > 5, shortSpecies, substr(Species, 1, 5))`. then, you enter the body of `make_new_col_expr` function. At this stage the variable `inputDT` is a promise object with value slot as nothing, expression slot as `dt.iris`, environment slot as Global Environment (because this is the environment the function as called from). so when you `substitute(inputDT)`, the result is `dt.iris` (the expression slot).

3. If you want the input of the function to be strings instead of expressions as per point 2, then:

```r
make_new_col_str <- function(inputDT, cond, newColName, construction) {
    ll <- substitute(
        dt[cond, newColName := construction],
        list(
            dt = substitute(inputDT),
            cond = if (missing(cond) || !nzchar(cond)) substitute() else str2lang(cond),
            newColName = str2lang(newColName),
            construction = str2lang(construction)
        )
    )
    cat(deparse(ll), "\n")
    eval(ll)
}
make_new_col_str(dt.iris, "Sepal.Length > 5", "shortSpecies", "substr(Species, 1, 5)")
make_new_col_str(dt.iris, , "shortSpecies", "substr(Species, 1, 5)")
```

Basically, you use `str2lang` to convert the string to expression. This is similar to `parse(text = "...")`, however, using `str2lang` is more succinct and  clear to the reader. That being said, this approach utilizes string, so, I would urge you to avoid this and choose point 2 above.

PS: I cut my teeth on finding solutions to problems similar to your question here (i.e., [programming on data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html)) before starting to understand `substitute` and stuffs related to *computing on the language*.